# How to connect to specific database using JDBC and Google Apps Script

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, jdbc, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to connect to a Google Cloud MySQL 5.7 instance using GAS and JDBC. I'm able to run the following without error:

`var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://my-instance-111111:us-central1:mydbname", user,userPwd)`

But this doesn't connect to a specific database, i.e. when I run

```js
var stmt = conn.createStatement();
var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT col FROM myTable;');
```

I get `Error Exception: No database selected`.

One approach to try to fix:

The [GAS docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc#getcloudsqlconnectionurl) indicate that I can use advanced parameters to include the DB name, but when I run `var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://my-instance-111111:us-central1:mydbname", user,userPwd,mydbname)` ,

I get `Exception: The parameters (String,String,String,String) don't match the method signature for Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection`.

A collection of `getCloudSqlConnection` statements that I've tried based on a number of StackOverflow posts:

```js
var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://my-instance-111111:us-central1:mydbname/mydbname", user,userPwd)

var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://my-instance-111111:us-central1:mydbname:3306/mydbname", user,userPwd)

var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://my-instance-111111:us-central1:mydbname:3307/mydbname", user,userPwd)
```

For the above statements, I also tried replacing `my-instance-111111:us-central1:mydbname` with the public IP supplied on the GC overview webpage. All return `Exception: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.`

I'm using user root and the appropriate password. I can enter the DB via the command line with the user and password that I'm supplying in GAS, so I don't think I'm supplying the wrong user and password.

**Edit:**
I went back to the docs like @AddonDepot mentioned and realized that I need to pass an object, but I still can't get this work....

```js
var obj = {
             connectTimeoutSeconds: 15,
             database: "mydbname",
             instance: "my-instance-111111:us-central1:mydbname",
             password: userPwd,
             queryTimeoutSeconds: 15,
             user: user   };



var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://my-instance-111111:us-central1:mydbname", obj);
```

returns

`Exception: The following connection properties are unsupported: database,instance,connectTimeoutSeconds,queryTimeoutSeconds.` .

Did I do something wrong in creating the object? I'm guessing not, because GAS recognizes `user` and `password`. Why wouldn't it recognize the other advanced parameters?

Comment: There are 3 variants of the `getCloudSqlConnection()` function with different method signatures (ie. distinguished by the number and types of parameters passed to the function). Read the documentation again to clarify usage.

Comment: Are you able to remotely connect using a different method?

Comment: @Martí Yes, I can fully access the DB from the terminal on my local computer. To do this, I use the exact same user and password as used in the GAS script.

Answer (score 1):

We have to distinguish between database system instances (sometimes referred simply as database; I'll use instances) and databases within them. That means that you may have an instance but may not have created any database in it.

You can use Apps Script to create a new database in your instance:

```js
const connectionName = 'connection-name:for-your:instance'
const dbName = 'database'
const username = 'user'
const password = 'password'

function createDB() {
  const conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(`jdbc:google:mysql://${connectionName}`, username, password)
  conn.createStatement().execute('CREATE DATABASE ' + dbName)
}
```

Once you have the database created in your instance you can use it:

```js
function useDB() {
  const conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(`jdbc:google:mysql://${connectionName}/${dbName}`, username, password)

  // Use conn
}
```

### References

- [JDBC (Google Apps Script guide)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc)